# Android Gradle Build Failed

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been using android studio and there where 17 errors messages after gradle build finished. I always try to rebuild but still same error.

Message in Grade Console :

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\Exam1\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Error:error: '67' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:error: '176' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:error: '67' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:error: '176' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:error: '67' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:error: '176' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'67' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'176' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'67' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'176' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'67' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:'176' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_width (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294].
Error:failed linking file resources.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Failed to execute aapt

Information:BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
Information:17 errors
Information:0 warnings`
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: set `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties`. Or follow complete guide here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: the problem is exist in this attr.xml file."Error:error: '67' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_height (attr) dimension|enum [fill_parent=4294967295, match_parent=4294967295, wrap_content=4294967294]."please provide valid dimensions there in the file

Comment: can you please send activity_main.xml file and then i check what is exact problem. 
or you can check dimension (width and height) in your xml file. you can also solve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're not using units for dimensions. You should use "dp" or other commonly used units. 
More info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension